# Orientdb in distributed mode: how to manage cluster Id's in distributed mode

Tags: distributed, orientdb

According to the documentation here http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Distributed-Architecture.html under the heading **Creation of records (documents, vertices and edges)** it states that

> In distributed mode the RID is assigned with cluster locality. If you have class Customer and 3 nodes (node1, node2, node3), you'll have these clusters:

- customer with id=#15 (this is the default one, assigned to node1)
- customer_node2 with id=#16
- customer_node3 with id=#17

This would imply that you cannot rely on the clusterID in your code. For example, selecting a record like this

```
select from #15:1
```

would break in a distributed setup, because once node1 fails and node2 takes over, you'll have to select

```
select from #16:1
```

My question is, is it the responsibility of the programmer to handle which clusterID to use, or is this automatically handled by OrientDB, in which case

```
select from #15:1
```

will always work, not matter which node is up or down?

Comment: That depends if you have a totally replicated database or you have shards. With sharding you can say that some cluster, let's say 15, it's only replicated in node1 and node2. And in that case, that query will fail if both these nodes are down.

Comment: Hi Vito - it is purely a replicated database for high availability purposes. If one server loses network connectivity I want a "hot backup" ready and up to date.

Comment: 15, 16, 17 is where each node will insert new instances of customer. E.g., node0 will insert #15:0, then #15:1..., node1 will insert #16:0, then #16:1...
But all these instances will be replicated in all nodes. So, I don't think you have a problem.

Comment: Thank you. But my question is: how do I pinpoint a record. The custerID is directly linked to the recordID, it's one and the same thing (ie #15:1). So in non distibuted mode, select * from #15:1 will always work. But the manual isn't clear on how to deal with this from your app. Should the app detect that node1 is down, and then start selecting from #16:1 instead of #15:1

Comment: But #15:1 is replicated in node1, node2 and node3; node1 goes down, the query will still work.

Comment: Sorry I see what you mean. You're saying that #15:1 should exists on all 3 nodes, therefore doing a select from #15:1 will work on all nodes. This leads me to the next question: is #16:1 and #17:1 then purely used internally by OrientDB, and should a programmer building a purely replicated database ignore these other clusters when they are coding?

Comment: #16:1 and #17:1 will only exist if you insert from node2 and node3.